# Having two different php frameworks on one single domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, ubuntu, laravel

We're transferring an old project on an old version of Zend Framework to Laravel. To make life a bit easier we're thinking of running both apps at the same time.

Let's say we have built a new blog in Laravel, which is the easiest way to accomplish this:

http://example.com/blog -> run index.php in /var/www/laravel-project/public/index.php
http://example.com/something_else -> run index.php in /var/www/zend-project/public/index.php

**.htaccess solution**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /laravel/public/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/(.+) /laravel/public/assets/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^images/(.+) /zend/public_html/images/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /zend/public_html/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Do you have full access to your Apache configuration, or is this shared hosting?

Comment: @halfer I have full access to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /laravel/public/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/(.+) /laravel/public/assets/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^images/(.+) /zend/public_html/images/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /zend/public_html/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could set up a rewrite condition that targets only specific segments, and route those to one of the frameworks, something like this (warning: untested)...

```
# Laravel Requests
RewriteCond $1 ^(blog)
RewriteRule ^ laravel/public/index.php [L]

# Zend Requests
RewriteCond $1 ^(something_else)
RewriteRule ^ zend/public/index.php [L]

# Assets
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php)
RewriteRule ^ all/public/$0 [L]
```

For Laravel you'll need to alter a few paths in public/index.php and other places so that it knows where it is; I assume this is the same for Zend too?

Comment: I didn't think my example would work out of the box - apache rewrite rules like this almost require a degree in apache to construct and understand ;)

Comment: @Emil, turn on mod_rewrite logging to understand what's going on. Check the manual on how to do so.